# Confusion regarding convex and affine set

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

I am a bit confused regarding convex and affine set. When they mention set, does it mean the set consisting of all the points belonging to the line or shape respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A line or a shape is typically *defined* as a set of points, namely the set of points that you think of as "belonging to" or "lying on" the shape.